# C# Add items if they are between a date

Tags: c#, date

I've created a program will need to add items if the items are between a date, this is the code I use:

`if (day >= fromDay - 1 && day <= tillDay && month >= fromMonth - 1 && month <= tillMonth && year >= fromYear - 1 && year <= tillYear)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(OpenFiles[m_index].getFileName());
                    }`

The code works fine but it has a fault in it: It checks if the day, month and year is between the start and stop.
So even you want to add something from the 19.02.2011 till the 15.04.2011, it doens't add or see anything. Please help me with this.

Comment: Use `DateTime` instances to do this kind of comparison in a sane manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compare *dates* rather than the components of the dates:

```
// Presumably you can determine these once... (possibly rename to earliestValid
// and latestValid, or something like that?)
DateTime from = new DateTime(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay);
DateTime to = new DateTime(toYear, toMonth, toDay);

// Then for each candidate...
...
DateTime date = new Date(year, month, day);
if (date >= from && date <= to)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(...);
}
```

(Of course, for a *date* type instead of date and time, have a look at [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) :)

Comment: oh my god, Jon is awake - we "earthlings" can go to bed ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime fromTime;
DateTime toTime;
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

if (currentTime >= fromTime && currentTime <= toTime)
{
 //to do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work this way:

```
var dateFrom = new DateTime(yearFrom, monthFrom, dayFrom);
var dateTo = new DateTime(yearTo, monthTo, dayTo);
var actualDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
if ((dateFrom < actualDate) && (actualDate < dateTo))
{
    // Do something
}
```

If you compare the parts of the dates seperately, it won't work (as you already found out :-D )

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a date out of the from and toDate and from the actual date and do this>

```
if(fromDate < date && date <= tillDate)
{
}
```